# I keep getting "Failed to load resource" when I try to start an React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

So I'm working on a React App using Webstorm for IDE. As far as I can tell everything seems to be configured properly, but somehow when I try to run the app it would throw an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Here is a sample of script in the index:

```js
<script>
    try {
        Typekit.load({
            async: true
        });
    } catch (e) {}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/fonts/Numbers.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

...From server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const renderIndex = function (req, res) {
  console.warn(__dirname + '/app/' + 'index.tpl.html');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/app/', 'index.tpl.html'));
};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Your app listening on port 3000!')
```

```html
<p>
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v9.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~prestart: webpack-react-redux@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: webpack-react-redux@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/blkbox/Desktop/Chris'/Quantdir/quantum-express-server/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
9 verbose lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/blkbox/Desktop/Chris'/Quantdir/quantum-express-server
10 silly lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node server' ]
11 silly lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle webpack-react-redux@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: webpack-react-redux@1.0.0 start: `node server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid webpack-react-redux@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/blkbox/Desktop/Chris'/Quantdir/quantum-express-server
16 verbose Darwin 14.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "start" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"
18 verbose node v9.2.0
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
</p>
```

What I want to accomplish is to have the app run in the browser, but continue getting an error. A response will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the first forward slash from the path
`src='dist/app.bundle.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to confirm that the entry point path is indeed correct? "/dist/app.bundle.js"

Comment: Yes, the entry point is set to here: module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app/index.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add server route `/` which returns your index html

```
app.get('/',function (req, res) { res.sendFile(pathToYourHTML) })
```